# SQLDepedency ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

In an ASP.NET MVC 6 application how would start and stop the sql dependency?

In previous versions you would use the Global.asax Application_Start event, but asp.net mvc 6 doesn't have this event.

```
 //Start SqlDependency with application initialization
 SqlDependency.Start(connString);

 // Stop SqlDependency
 SqlDependency.Stop()
```

Comment: Did you reference System.Data.SqlClient ?

Comment: Yes but asp.net 5 doesn't have a concept of global.asax so I'm not sure when I should be calling the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place startup code in your Startup.cs file

Try something like this

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime lifetime) {
        lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => {
            //Start SqlDependency with application initialization
            SqlDependency.Start(connString);
        });

        lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => {
            // Stop SqlDependency
            SqlDependency.Stop()
        });
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

But be carefull, SqlDependency is not available in  dnx core

Comment: Thanks for that, what would the alternative be to using sqlDependency?
With your example above with the sqlDependency stop straight away? as opposed to adding to to application_end

`protected void Application_Start()
    {
            //...
       SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString); 
    }
    
    
    protected void Application_End()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString); 
    }`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Although I have never used before the ApplicationStopping event, so I don't know if it is ok to use it for your situation. give it a try and let me know. Also have a look at this https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/430c55440b3528427d934c074264ef8c8cbdf739/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions/IApplicationLifetime.cs
Maybe you want to use ApplicationStopped instead

Comment: Thanks for that I didn't know those events existed

Comment: Where did you hookup `SqlDependency.OnChange`?  trying to figure this out so that I dont have to do it inside a Hub

Comment: @salek I have never used the OnChange event, but I think that anywhere in the Configure method should work...